# Creating Bins in Tableau for Days in a Week

Tags: tableau-api

Could someone please explain me creating BINS based on Weekdays in Tableau?  I tried creating different Calculation Fields but it won't work

Answer (score 3):

You're working too hard.

Tableau already knows how to bin values by dates at many levels of granualarity: such as year, month, day, weekday, hour etc. So you don't need to create a new field to bin dates by the day of the week. (creating bins is not difficult, it's just already available in this case)

Just put a discrete (blue) date or datetime field on a shelf. You'll see the date level of granularity displayed like, say, YEAR(MyDateField) with a leading plus sign.

You can either

- click on the plus sign to drill down by adding a second level, say MONTH(MyDateField)
  or
- right click on the field to select the date level of granularity you want

Answer (score 2):

Alex's Answer is exactly correct, Tableau will perform the operation automatically.  What is great about is that you can select various formats (Full day name, number, 1 letter or 3 letter day etc.).

However if you absolutely need to you can used this formula:

```
datepart('weekday',[Date])
```

to give you the 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday) value if you need it for something other reason, say another calculation.